# take value of argument into array as an index number

Tags: bash

```
argument_number=$#
for ((i = 2; i <= $argument_number; i++))
do
echo ${lower[$i]]}
done
```

I want to take argument value into array as index number for example if my second argumnet is 15 want to achive lower[15] but it gives lower[2] how can  I do ,is there any suggestion,help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the indices into array `${lower[@]}` are given by command-line arguments; in this case, you can simply use:

```
shift # skip the 1st argument
for index; do # this loops over all command-line arguments; same as: for index in "$@"; do
  echo "${lower[index]}"
done
```

Note:

- I've *double-quoted* `${lower[index]}` so as to protect the value from unwanted interpretation by the shell - unless you specifically want the shell to perform word-splitting and globbing on a variable value, you should double-quote all your variable references.
- Array subscripts in Bash are evaluated in *arithmetic* context, which is why variable `index` can be referenced *without* the usual `$` prefix.

Comment: I have lower array which has romen numerals from i to xxix and when I give 14 (for example ) as second argument I want to reach lower[14] not lower[2] which is given by lower[$i]

Comment: @karabugra05: I'm not sure I _fully_ understand, but I _think_ that's what my solution is doing - please try it.

Comment: i am grateful to you,it happened,I achived my goal